# How to deploy web application having angular 6 as front end, Asp dot net core on backend and SQL server as database on nginx using docker

Tags: sql-server, angular, docker, nginx, asp.net-core-webapi

I have web application which uses angular 6 on client side,asp .net core on backend and sql server as a database.
I want to deploy this web apllication on nginx server using docker.
I have installed docker on windows and created nginx container also,but I dont know how to map host application to container and how to serve application.

Note : operating system is windows.

Answer (score 0):

Use Docker-compose (https://docs.docker.com/compose/). You can connect your containers via extra_hosts and start your app with one command